# Add label values to multiple line chart in the same axis matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this df:

```
      CODE   MONTH  TMIN    %PV
0     000130  01    23.4      12
1     000130  02    23.8      15
2     000130  03    23.6      18
3     000130  04    23.6      11
4     000130  05    23.1      11
       ...  ..   ...    ...
1615  158313  08     12.1     10
1616  158313  09     12.2     22
1617  158313  10     23       25
1618  158313  11     51       21
1619  158313  12     28       11
```

I'm plotting multiple line charts in a same axis:

```
for code, data in df.groupby('CODE'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 15))
  
    plt.plot(data.iloc[0:12]['MONTH'],data.iloc[0:12]['TMIN'],'o--',color='black',linewidth=8,marker='o',markersize=12)    
    plt.plot(data.iloc[12:24]['MONTH'],data.iloc[12:24]['TMIN'],'o-',color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.plot(data.iloc[24:36]['MONTH'],data.iloc[24:36]['TMIN'],'o-',color='green', marker='o')
```

I want to add the value label of their corresponding `data['%PV']` value in every line chart.

I tried this:

```
for code, data in df.groupby('CODE'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 15))

    data1=data.iloc[0:12]
    data2=data.iloc[12:24]
    data3=data.iloc[24:36]
  
    plt.plot(data1['MONTH'],data1['TMIN'],'o--',color='black',linewidth=8,marker='o',markersize=12)    
    plt.plot(data2['MONTH'],data2['TMIN'],'o-',color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.plot(data3['MONTH'],data3['TMIN'],'o-',color='green', marker='o')

for df in (data2, data3):
    for index, v in df.iterrows():
       label = "{:.2f}".format(float(v['%PV']))
       plt.annotate(label, (v['MONTH'], v['%PV']), ha='center')
```

But this is not plotting any label, but when i change v['%PV'] for v['TMIN'] i got the labels

How can i get the v['%PV'] labels in the line chart?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do when you set `label`? I don't understand the point of formatting with 2 decimal places if you are using `int`.

Comment: @ProfessorPantsless was a mistake, i change it to float(). I want to make data['%VP'] values to be the value labels of the line chart.

Comment: The plots use `v['TMIN']` as the points; don't you want to use that in the `annotate` function and leave the `label` as is?

Comment: @ProfessorPantsless no, i want to use the annotate to show the label values of v['%PV']

Comment: Can you share the output of the plot to illustrate what you want to get?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment might not have been clear. Change the last line in the code to `plt.annotate(label, (v['MONTH'], v['TMIN']), ha='center')`; this should annotate the points in your plot with the values you want (leave the definition of `label` as is). Otherwise I think I am not clear on what you want to achieve.